# Lookup EC2 resource ID to which a known public IP address is associated, in Node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

Given a known public IP address (e.g. elastic IP) how can I look up the resource ID of the EC2 instance associated with it, in Node?

My ultimate intention is to start/stop the EC2 instance associated with a given public IP address from Node running in another EC2 instance in the same AWS account. I presume that I first have to find the resource ID of the instance I want to start/stop so that I can then call `ec2.startInstances()` with the resource ID, but at runtime I know only the public IP address of the instance to start/stop.

Comment: You can use the ec2 [describeinstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) API to find the details of a given node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `describeAddresses` Node API. It will list your ElasticIPs and which InstanceID each is assigned to. You can call the `startInstances()` from this.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeAddresses-property

For a non-elasticIP, you could perhaps add a startup script that causes the Instance to send its environment details somewhere you can store and reference instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [describeInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeInstances-property) with the `"ip-address"` filter to find the instance you're looking for. You can then use the instance id to stop the instance or do anything else you may need.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
ec2.describeInstances(
    {
        Filters: [
            {
                Name: "ip-address",
                Values: [
                    "5.5.5.5"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else { // successful response
            data.Reservations.forEach(r => {
                r.Instances.forEach(i => {
                    console.log(i.InstanceId);
                })
            })
        }
    }
);
```